# Would have rescued you vs would rescue you

Tags: conditional-constructions

A -- Jim has been abducted, we need to rescue him
B -- It's too risky, we I can't go.
A -- **But he would have done the same for you.**

1. I don't know **how to conceptualise this construction**.

So what I think this grammar asks me [I'll put myself in B's shoes for a moment] to do is to imagine an alternate reality where I'm abducted and Jim comes to save me. And now I make this imaginative framework a past seen from the present and then I can say "right, If something like this had happened, Jim would have saved me" and yet it's still speculation which is why I say "would have".

pretty sure this is nonsense but maybe it will shed some light on my confusion

2. Also, **why not use there the 2nd conditional** (if you were abducted, Jim would do the same for you [rescuing]). Is it precluded by the fact that Jim couldn't perform that act because his trapped himself?

Comment: Indeed, I _would_ say "But he would do the same for you," meaning 'if your situations were reversed'.

Comment: "he would have done" sounds fine to me - although it suggests it is no longer possible for him to do the same thing in reverse.